# If I don’t have any parameters, CommandLineParser with C# do not display my method

Tags: c#, command-line-parser

This code using the CommandLineParser library works. However, as soon as I don’t set a parameter, I can’t get the result of the return of the method DisplayHelp. My code works when I have parameters but don't when there aren't. This is my code :

```
int result;

var parser = new CommandLine.Parser(with => with.HelpWriter = null);
var parserResult = parser.ParseArguments<ProgramOptions>(args);

ProgramOptions opts = null;
Program.options = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<ProgramOptions>(args)
    .WithParsed(options => { opts = options; })
    .WithNotParsed(errs => DisplayHelp(parserResult, errs));
if ((opts == null) || (args.Length == 0))
{
    result = (int)ApplicationResult.HelpRequested;
}
else
{
    result = MainWithOptions(opts);
}
```

1. with a valid param Program.options is initialized with the parameters extracted from command line args => OK
2. with an invalid command line args, the help is displayed. => OK
3. with no command line args, the help is not displayed => That's not what I want.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: could you please be more specific than "doesn't work"? do you get any errors, and if so, which ones? how does the program behave and how _should_ it behave? i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: I just edit my post to be more specific. Hope you will understand